# What function names to make dynamic Database calls and page populations

Tags: jquery, dynamic-content

I'm not looking for anyone to hold my hand or tell me what to write, but I need to know the name of functions in JQuery to do a few things. This was I can research these functions and then determine the syntax and way to implement them in my work, ultimately learning this along the way.

Basically what I am looking to do is have a page look to a database peridoically (frequently) and check for changes, specifically for additional posts on a facebook-like wall.

I also need to know what functions or things I should look for in jQuery so that I can handle this and other dynamic functions on a page. Another function is to check when someone has new messages to display the number (or any notifications) on a certain area, and to commit data (text from a post) to a specified area on a page. I already know how to write CSS and mark up for this type of thing, but I just don't know the names of the functions to concern myself with to include in the scripts.

Again, I will figure out how to write it and how to determine the syntax, or intuitive ways to implement the jquery, just can someone point me in the right direction to be able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will definitely need ajax(that's also the name of the jquery function) to make the requests to the db. Furthermore I recommend to read the jquery documentation and study some jquery tutorials. If you have sth like a basic implementation you can ask a more detailed specific question.

Comment: I know it will require AJAX. For instance if someone was asking "I need to implement pictures in a page that when clicked take you to another page or site." I would say "well you want to concern yourself with a href and img tags..."

(I wouldn't be a troll and vote down a sincere question.) Sorry that I am not here asking some advanced question.. so to whoever voted it down go ahead and pat yourself on the back for doing such a good thing, but I am trying to learn how to actually do something so I came here to see if I can be pointed in the right direction of where to start.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no such simple answer. The only thing I can tell you, is that you will have to use some of the jquery ajax functions like post, get or ajax. You will furthermore need some selector functions like find, children or parents. And you will need to manipulate the contents of some Dom elements, so you will probably need functions like remove, html or attr. But still, your question is too generic.

Comment: I know it is a pretty broad question. But what you have answered is what I am looking for. I don't want anyone to do it for me, but exactly what you did - let me know where to look and what I should be thinking about doing. Thanks a million Garzun :-)